# How to get products available quantity for individual stock (Odoo11)

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

I am using **odoo11(python3)** and *develop a custom module.*

I would like to get products quantity (by hand or forecast) for an individual stock house.

Just I select any individual stockhouse and show product quantity for this stockhouse.
Actually, my target is two things
1.Products total available quantity
2.Products available quantity based on location
This is my code

```
class Threshold(models.Model):
    _name="threshold.threshold"
    main_location=fields.Many2many("stock.warehouse", string="Main Location")
    product=fields.Many2many("product.template", string="Product")
    category=fields.Many2one("product.category", string="Category")
    attribute=fields.Many2many("product.attribute", string="Attribute")
    threshold_value=fields.Integer(string="Threshold Value")
    transfer_quantity=fields.Integer(string="Transfer Quantity")
    status_button=fields.Selection([('0','Active'),('1','Dissmiss')], default='0', index=True, string="Status")
    threshold_selection=fields.Selection([('0','Product'),('1','Category'),], default= '0', index=True, string="Threshold Selection")

product_quantity=fields.Integer(compute="_product_based_on_warehouse", store=True)

@api.depends('main_location','product_quantity')
def _product_based_on_warehouse(self):
    count_products = 0 
self.env['product.template'].with_context(warehouse=self.main_location).search([], limit=1)
self.product_quantity=products print(f'Product Quantity: {self.product_quantity}')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to load/browse the products with a special context value `warehouse` to get all the quantity values for all, one or multiple warehouses.

```py
# load all products and use a warehouse id
products = self.env['product.product'].with_context(warehouse=1).search([])
# load one product and use a warehouse name
products = self.env['product.product'].with_context(warehouse="Main Warehouse").search([], limit=1)
# load product with ID 1 and use a list of warehouse IDs
products = self.env['product.product'].with_context(warehouse=[1,2]).browse([1])
```

You can use the 4 quantity fields of products to get the quantity values you need. There is also an option to use `location` as context value in the same manner as with `warehouse`.

If you want to know where this is coming from look into the methods `_compute_quantities`, `_compute_quantities_dict` and the most important one `_get_domain_locations`.

Comment: `product_quantity=fields.Integer(compute="_product_based_on_warehouse", store=True)
    @api.depends('main_location','product_quantity')
    def _product_based_on_warehouse(self):
        count_products = self.env['product.template'].with_context(warehouse=self.main_location).search([], limit=1)
        self.product_quantity=products
        print(f'Product Quantity: {self.product_quantity}')`

Comment: Please don't post so much code in comments, it isn't readable. `self.main_location` is a recordset and not an ID or a warehouse name. Please change that to `self.main_location.id`. That `search()` will return products as a recordset (in this case exactly one product) and not quantities! It will return a recordset where the computed quantity fields of the found products are computed with the location or warehouse "in mind". So it should be `self.product_quantity=products.qty_available` if i recall the field name correct.